# Was the font for TeX commands change?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting

In my opinion the font looks like Times and not like CM as before.

Commands like `\sum` for example are producing different kind of serifs.

Was the font change or I'm wrong?

---

Here is a sample. For me the font is not the default.
[image]

Comment: Have you changed browser/OS/computer? Also what is your current setup?

Comment: If it looks like Times now then it must be because you are using STIX fonts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 with Firefox. The only difference from yesterday to today was that I's testing some LuaLaTeX files, changing some default fonts with TeXLive and TeXStudio. Nothing related to my linux system.

Comment: I don't know how to restore the font. These Times fonts are so ugly.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot so we can compare if we are seeing the same as you?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, edited with sample.

Comment: No, that really looks like something local to your computer.

Comment: Using my terminal history I found that I run `fc-cache -sfv` yesterday.

Comment: TeXLive now ships with STIX (and XITS) fonts. (Also, I find Computer Modern ugly. Tastes vary. :p)

Answer (score 4):

**I found the problem/solution.**

Yesterday, trying to use `otf` fonts within TeXLive, I copied the file below to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` and after I run `sudo fc-cache`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
<dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
<dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

Today, I moved that file and run that command again. Now everything is fine like before.
Thanks.